# Running PM2 on Digital Ocean App Platform

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, pm2

I'm trying to run PM2 for my Node application that is hosted on the Digital Ocean App Platform. I have no issues running my app with `node index.js` but when I try to run `pm2 start index.js` I end up with a failed deployment. I haven't seen anywhere saying otherwise, but is it possible to use PM2 on the App Platform?

From my deploy logs:

```
[2023-02-28 07:03:29] > pm2 start index.js
[2023-02-28 07:03:30] [PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/workspace/.pm2
[2023-02-28 07:03:30] [PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
[2023-02-28 07:03:30] [PM2] Starting /workspace/index.js in fork_mode (1 instance)
[2023-02-28 07:03:31] [PM2] Done.
[2023-02-28 07:03:31] ┌─────┬──────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
[2023-02-28 07:03:31] │ id  │ name     │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
[2023-02-28 07:03:31] ├─────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
[2023-02-28 07:03:31] │ 0   │ index    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 39       │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 0b       │ apps     │ enabled  │
[2023-02-28 07:03:31] └─────┴──────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
[2023-02-28 07:03:31] npm notice 
[2023-02-28 07:03:31] npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.19.3 -> 9.5.1
[2023-02-28 07:03:31] npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.5.1>
[2023-02-28 07:03:31] npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.5.1` to update!
[2023-02-28 07:03:31] npm notice
```

```
Error message: Component Issues app_name failed to deploy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For health check to know if the app is running and the deployment was successful you'll have to run PM2 in the foreground.

```
pm2 start index.js --no-daemon
```